# How to do a custom asp.net routing (hardcoding the controller)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to create a route for the following urls:
www.mysite.com/user/username
www.mysite.com/user/username/pictures

I tried doing that with the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "UserProfile",
            "user/{sn}/{action}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", sn = "" }
        );
```

So if an action is not specified, you go to the index action.

However, it's not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is correct.

The order of the rules is important. Try to place this above all other rules.
And if it will intefere with other rules, you should provide some constraints for the best matches.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with maxnk, the code looks correct, it's probably just an ordering thing.  I'd suggest checking out the Route Debugger that Phil Haack wrote: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx.  It's very useful for these tricky route-ordering issues